# Having trouble saving input text to local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm making a planner application that allows inputted text to be saved to local storage by the hour and I cannot figure out how to fix my javascript to make it work.
HTML:

```
          <tr class="row" id="17">
            <th scope="time" id="hour17" class="time">17:00</th>
            <td><input type="text" class="textbox" id="h17input" onclick = "savePlan()"></td>
            <td class="btnContainer">
              <button class="saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
            </td>
          </tr>
```

JS:

```
var input = document.getElementById('input');

function savePlan() {
    localStorage.setItem(input.innerText);
    console.log(input);
    localStorage.getItem(input.innerText)
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: What error message are you seeing?

Comment: "Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present"

Answer (score 1):

need 2 parameters : `localStorage.setItem(keyName, keyValue);`. You are missing `keyName`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage.getItem` requires a `keyName` to store the value under a name. And you need to use the `value` property of the `input` instead of the `innerText`.

```
const button = document.querySelector('.saveBtn');
const input = document.getElementById('h17input');

button.addEventListener('click', savePlan);

function savePlan() {
  localStorage.setItem('plan', input.value);
}

function getPlan() {
  return localStorage.getItem('plan');
}
```

Comment: It didn't quite work, no error messages though. Still trying to troubleshoot. This answer does make sense to me. Not sure why it's not working

Comment: There was a small typo in my `getPlan` function. And I see that the `id` of the input in your HTML is different than in your JavaScript. Did that cause it to fail? I've edited my answer.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I checked my dev tools and under local storage is just saved 'plan' even though I typed something else in that textbox input. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Okay, strangely enough it works but only in firefox. I must be going crazy. My chrome live server extension wont work but firefox does.

Comment: Take a little step back. I'm seeing that your input in the HTML also an `onclick` attribute. Remove it as it will also call `savePlan` when clicking on the input, which surely is not what you want.

Comment: Yep, I took that out too. For some reason it didn't change much

Comment: Could you create a code snippet that we can run to help you debug? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and [codepen](https://codepen.io/) are services that can help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can think that `localstorage` works "like" an object, with key and values. If you want to store something there, you need to enter a key (`keyName`) and a value (your `input`). Now, if you want to get a value from there, you just need the key.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

So, in your case:

```
var input = document.getElementById('input');

function savePlan() {
    // store input.value
    localStorage.setItem('myCustomStorage:month', input.value); 
    
    // return input.value on localStorage
    return localStorage.getItem('myCustomStorage:month') 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made something like this:

*Update: I added an id (`saveBtn`) to the button.

```js
let textbox = document.getElementById('h17input');
let saveBtn = document.getElementById('saveBtn');
saveBtn.addEventListener('click',savePlan);
function savePlan() {
    //localStorage.setItem(input.innerText);
    window.localStorage.setItem("saved_data", JSON.stringify(textbox.value))
    //localStorage.getItem(input.innerText)
    let  savedItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("saved_data"));
    console.log(savedItem);
};
```

Comment: I tried this but got "cannot read event listener of null" :(

Comment: @hannahatl How yea, I added id to the button of `saveBtn`